# Showing a function is constant - Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem.

$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is an analytic function in $D$ ($D$ is connected and open).

If $u, v$ fulfill the relation $G(u(x,y), v(x,y))= 0 $ in $D$ for some function ($G:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$) with the property

Show that $f$ is constant.

In this question, does the condition imply that $G$ is differentiable? If so, which part ? And should i use chain rule to solve this?

Comment: You have accepted an answer to this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740961/showing-that-an-function-f-is-constant

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy yes but i still wonder in which part of the question implies that $G$ is differentiable?

Comment: Implicit in the question is that the partials exist, however this does not imply that $G$ is differentiable.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you that cleared up a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is non constant and analytic it is an open map.

Then $f(B(z_0,\epsilon))$ contains an open set $O$ containing $f(z_0)$, and
$G(x,y) = 0$ for $x+iy \in O$. In particular, ${\partial G(x,y) \over \partial x} = {\partial G(x,y) \over \partial y} = 0$ for such $x+iy$ which
contradicts the hypothesis.

Hence $f$ is constant on each component and hence on $D$.